# How to use columns in html-to-pdfmake?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdfmake

[https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/document-definition-object/columns/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnMMC.png)

Help me Please Thankyou.
T-T.

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to convert HTML to use in pdfmake? If so, here's a converter: https://aymkdn.github.io/html-to-pdfmake/index.html

Comment: question asks about columns using html-to-pdfmake. answer contains nothing about columns and just points to the tool the question asked about.  (to be fair the question could use some work!)